# How to create settings.notification_settings with Python using Databricks SDK?

Tags: python, databricks, databricks-sdk

I have a job in databricks I am cloning using Python + the Databricks SDK. I replace certain attributes with new ones during the cloning.

This works fine until I try to clone a job that does not have job.settings.notification_settings.

When I try to create it, it simply does not work without any error.

I've tried

```
if not hasattr(job_set_env.settings, 'notification_settings'):
     setattr(job_set_env.settings,"notification_settings",{"no_alert_for_skipped_runs":False,"no_alert_for_canceled_runs":False})
```

And I've tried:

```
setattr(job_set_env.settings.notification_settings,"no_alert_for_skipped_runs",False)
setattr(job_set_env.settings.notification_settings,"no_alert_for_canceled_runs",False)
```

What is the way to properly set job_set_env.settings.notification_settings if it does not begin to start with?

Comment: Are you using `databricks-sdk` package or old SDK from `databricks-cli` ?

Comment: databricks-sdk. I had to make my own class to do this, but I know its not the right way...NotificationSettings:
    def __init__(self, no_alert_for_skipped_runs=False, no_alert_for_canceled_runs=False):
        self.no_alert_for_skipped_runs = no_alert_for_skipped_runs
        self.no_alert_for_canceled_runs = no_alert_for_canceled_runs

    def as_dict(self):
        return {
            'no_alert_for_skipped_runs': self.no_alert_for_skipped_runs,
            'no_alert_for_canceled_runs': self.no_alert_for_canceled_runs
        }

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the `JobNotificationSettings` class from the `databricks.sdk.jobs` package to use it.  See the [source code](https://github.com/databricks/databricks-sdk-py/blob/main/databricks/sdk/service/jobs.py#L747) for reference.